# What could be the matrix of Transformation that has no effect on vectors? The vectors are $T(x)=(x)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, matrix-equations

We call this matrix Identity and denote it by $I$. But I am not clear with how to assume one matrix to proceed with its solution. The Form of Transformation here is $\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$ subspaces. I am quoting the exact question here:

All of the transformations here have the form $T: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$.
Find the matrix of the transformation that has no effect on vectors, that is $T(x)= x$. We call this matrix the identity matrix and denote it by $I$.

Comment: If it's true for all $x$, then in particular $T(e_1)=e_1$ and $T(e_2)=e_2$. Not a lot of freedom as far as matrices which can do that.

Comment: The matrix representation of $T$ depends on the choices of the bases used.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe: except in this special case it doesn’t, any basis will give the same matrix.

Comment: @Joppy Not if you chose two different bases ...

Answer (score 1):

Any transformation is represented by a matrix. Now, for a $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ transformation, this would be a $2 \times 2$ matrix

$$T = \begin{bmatrix}a & b \\ c & d\end{bmatrix}$$

Now, we are given that

$$T\vec{x} = \vec{x}$$

$$\implies \begin{bmatrix}a & b \\ c & d\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}ax+by \\ cx + dy \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}x \\ y\end{bmatrix}$$

Since this is true for all $x,y \in R$, we have

$$a = 1, b = 0, c = 0, d =1$$

Answer (score 0):

$T(x)=x\implies (T-I)x=0\forall x\in\mathbb R^2$

The minimal polynomial must be $m(t)=t-1$ which suggests $T$ is diagonizable. $m(t)$ also divides the characteristic polynomial so that is $c(t)=(t-1)^2$. Looking for the possible Jordan canonical forms for the matrix representation of $T$,  you have $T=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$ ($\color{red}{Why?}$)

Comment: Is involving minimal polynomials and Jordan canonical forms an appropriate answer to a question which is basically “what is the identity matrix”?

Comment: That just describes a different approach from what is described in previous answer.